# Update C# datagridviews in separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have a windows form with a datagridview and some buttons. One of the buttons when clicked will call a method called `loadMyData()` that reads some data from a csv and puts them in three datagridviews in the form.

The code is something like this:

```
public partial class NewForm : Form
{

    private void loadData_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) // load market data, create a base copy and update gridview
    {
        ThreadStart thread1Start = new ThreadStart(loadMyData);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(thread1Start);
        t1.Start();          
    }

    public void loadMyData()
    {
    dataMap = dataLoader.newLoadTheData(dataMap, grid1, grid2) 


    }
}
```

where `dataLoader.newLoadTheData` is a static method that takes as input my datagridviews (grid1, grid2) and a dictionary (dataMap). The method simply reads some data from a csv and put the numbers in the 2 datagridviews. These are updated from this method and an updated dictionary (dataMap) is also returned by the method. It all works fine when the method `loadMyData()` is executed normally but I get this error when I execute it as thread:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'grid1' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

I realize that I might be using something like "invoke" but I really can't find a clear example that shows how to do this in my case. Can anyone help with tjis situation? How should I change the code to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

When working with your grid from the other thread, you should do something like this:

```
if (grid1.InvokeRequired)
   grid1.Invoke(new Action(() => { /*do my stuff here*/ })
else
{
   /*do my stuff here*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The grids are updated by the static method `dataLoader.newLoadTheData` and is simply adding a row for each value that is found in the csv (at the end all non-empty cells in the csv will be in the gridview). So should I put the code `Invoke` in the method `dataLoader.newLoadTheData`?

Comment: So everytime I do something with the grids in the thread I need to use `grid.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* read from csv and update gridview adding one row*/ })`? And basically in the `else` part (so when `! grid.InvokeRequired`) I still need to put the same code that reads from csv and populate gridview so that it can still run when is not running in multi-threading? Is this code duplication necessary?

Comment: You can put that code in a function which you can call from both places. Basically, that if allows you to take different actions depending on the InvokeRequired property. In your case, you want to do the same thing, just on different threads.

Comment: So I can leave the csv reading part as it is (since there is no grid involved there) but the create another function inside the `dataLoader.newLoadTheData` method and pass the grids as input. Then the new function will go in the `Invoke` like: `if (grid.InvokeRequired)
   grid.Invoke(new Action(() => { newFunct(grid1,grid2)})
else
{
   newFunct(grid1,grid2)
}`

Comment: Anywhere is fine as long as it gets run when supposed to. I would put it in newLoadTheData (or another method wich gets called by newLoadTheData) since this is the method which gets called from the different threads you spawn.

Answer (score 0):

You have to marshal the call back to the UI thread.

Are you using WinForms or WPF?

In WPF you can use the Dispatcher.

In WinForms:

Try

```
// Get the UI thread's context in the constructor.
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();


        // Then its possible to start a task directly on the UI thread
        var token = Task.Factory.CancellationToken;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            this.label1.Text = "Task past first work section...";
        }, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, context);
```

EDIT:

The reason you are getting this error is because you are trying to access the Grid control from another thread. In general, most UI applications are in a STA(Single Threaded Affinity) model, where any interactions with the UI must be done on the "UI" thread which is usually the main/first thread the application starts on.

As you are loading the data on a **background** thread, after it is finished, you need a way to **Marshal**(invoke/run) the code which update the Grid on the **Main/UI** thread.

To achieve this, you create a TaskScheduler on the main thread by using its current SynchronizationContext (as in the constructor of the window/control the current context will be the UI thread) and than later you can pass that context into the Task.Factory.StartNew method as a parameter, so that it knows to "Marshal"(Invoke/Run) the code on the given "Context" which is the UI Thread

Comment: Thanks. It is a WinForm. Can you please explay how this woul work?

Answer (score 0):

**System.Threading.Tasks** allows you to easily create a child task and run a completion block when all is complete.  If you specify the UI context then the completion block will run in the UI thread, no need for `Invoke()`.

Code:

```
        var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
                              () =>
                              {
                                  // this runs in worker thread
                                  loadMyData(); 
                                  DoSomeLengthyJob();
                                  DoSomethingElse();
                              }) 
            .ContinueWith(t =>
                          {
                              // now we are in UI thread
                              // now update the UI with whatever you want
                              // with the results from your worker thread

                              dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                          }, ui);
```

### Tell me more

- Check out [this article by Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: But this way I can't run in parallel?

Comment: @mickG Incorrect.  When `loadMyData()` is invoked above it runs in a **separate thread**

Comment: It's just that I see a `.ContinueWith()` so If I have another method in it (e.g. update grids) then this will run after `loadMyData()`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @mickG `.ContinueWith()` runs last, that is correct. In that block update the UI with the results from your worker thread. I have updated my example to show additional things you can do in the worker thread block.